# Makefile with -std=c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile

I am writing a makefile for my program (that is tested and works)   The problem I can tell is that some how my '-std=c++11' is not running in the function.  The code pops out a unrecognized error that I dont get when I simply run 'g++ -o exe -std=c++11 *.cpp'.  Here is my make file.

```
HEADERS = card.h sortedLinkedList.h deck.h
OBJECTS = card.o sortedLinkedList.o deck.o main.o
exe: $(OBJECTS)
   g++ -std=c++11 $^ -o $@
%.o: %.cpp $(HEADERS)
   g++ -c -std=c++11 $< -o $@
clean:
   rm -i *.o exe
```

The output of my makefile is

```
me@root:~/Documents/CS216/Lab8$ make
g++    -c -o card.o card.cpp
card.cpp: In member function ‘void Card::print()’:
card.cpp:55:28: error: ‘to_string’ was not declared in this scope
       cardN=to_string(point);
                            ^
<builtin>: recipe for target 'card.o' failed
make: *** [card.o] Error 1
```

note: to_string() is not defined until c++11

```
daniel@Reimann:~/Documents/CS216/Lab8$ ls 
card.cpp  deck.cpp  Lab8      lab8source.zip        SortedLinkedList.h
card.h    deck.h    lab8.cpp  makefile              SortedLinkedList.o
card.o    deck.o    lab8.o    SortedLinkedList.cpp
```

Output of xxd makefile

```
00000000: 4845 4144 4552 5320 3d20 6361 7264 2e68  HEADERS = card.h
00000010: 2073 6f72 7465 644c 696e 6b65 644c 6973   sortedLinkedLis
00000020: 742e 6820 6465 636b 2e68 0a4f 424a 4543  t.h deck.h.OBJEC
00000030: 5453 203d 2063 6172 642e 6f20 536f 7274  TS = card.o Sort
00000040: 6564 4c69 6e6b 6564 4c69 7374 2e6f 2064  edLinkedList.o d
00000050: 6563 6b2e 6f20 6c61 6238 2e6f 0a4c 6162  eck.o lab8.o.Lab
00000060: 383a 2024 284f 424a 4543 5453 290a 0967  8: $(OBJECTS)..g
00000070: 2b2b 202d 7374 643d 632b 2b31 3120 245e  ++ -std=c++11 $^
00000080: 202d 6f20 2440 0a25 2e6f 3a20 252e 6370   -o $@.%.o: %.cp
00000090: 7020 2428 4845 4144 4552 5329 200a 0967  p $(HEADERS) ..g
000000a0: 2b2b 202d 6320 2d73 7464 3d63 2b2b 3131  ++ -c -std=c++11
000000b0: 2024 3c20 2d6f 2024 400a 636c 6561 6e3a   $< -o $@.clean:
000000c0: 0a09 726d 202d 6920 2a2e 6f20 4c61 6238  ..rm -i *.o Lab8
000000d0: 0a
```

Comment: I have my out put posted now

Comment: I am coding on a linux machine if that makes any difference but I don't see how it can.

Comment: Are you sure you are running the makefile that you posted and not some different makefile?

Comment: I just named the files generic things

Comment: What does `ls` output?

Comment: Can you post the output of `xxd makefile`?

Comment: Nice to get infos peace by peace... and also nice, that people downvote answers which should help, based on outdated infos from OP. So I am off, find your problems self... sorry, so I could not work together!

Comment: only one makefile as you can see from ls comannd do I need to save the file some special way?

Comment: @Klaus Your answer wasn't helpful because it was based on a guess that turned out to be incorrect. It was not based on outdated information, it was based on incomplete information. Consider asking for more information before writing up an answer, or accept that guesses can be wrong occasionally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is in this line:

```
HEADERS = card.h sortedLinkedList.h deck.h
#----------------^
```

You have specified a dependency on `sortedLinkedList.h`, but that file doesn't exist. You only have `SortedLinkedList.h` with a capital `S`.

The rule

```
%.o: %.cpp $(HEADERS)
    g++ -c -std=c++11 $< -o $@
```

is considered for making `card.o` but rejected because one of the prerequisites (namely `sortedLinkedList.h`) doesn't exist.

So `make` falls back to its built-in rule for making `.o` files from `.cpp` files, which is `$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c`.

`CXX` is set to `g++` by default, but `CPPFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` are empty. This explains the extra spaces between `g++` and `-c` in the output:

```
g++    -c -o card.o card.cpp
```

You can confirm this by running `make -r`, which disables all built-in rules. It should now fail to find a rule for making `card.o`.

To solve this, you should fix the capitalization of `SortedLinkedList.h`. You should also consider using the built-in rules and just set `CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11`.

Comment: You are right works not and thanks for the explanation and tips not just the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you want to use the `CXXFLAGS` implicit variable to specify this switch. I am not sure why the current pattern rule is failing, but using CXXFLAGS will allow getting rid of it entirely